# In C/C++ arithmetic operation inside of for statement arguments

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, constants, compiler-optimization

Let's say I have this code:

```
int v;
setV(&v);
for (int i = 0; i < v - 5; i++) {
  // Do stuff here, but don't use v.
}
```

Will the operation `v - 5` be run every time or will a modern compiler be smart enough to store it once and never run it again?

What if I did this:

```
int v;
setV(&v);
const int cv = v;
for (int i = 0; i < cv - 5; i++) {
  // Do stuff here. Changing cv is actually impossible.
}
```

Would the second style make a difference?

Comment: One would hope that the compiler optimizes this in both cases.  There is really one one way to find out though.  Compile it and check the assembly.

Comment: Depends. Do you pass the address of `v` to a function in the loop? If so, is the function in a different translation unit? If so, are link-time optimizations enabled?

Comment: In my real program, v is one of several variables set by reference by one function. It is never used inside of the loop. I don't know how to check compiled code.

Comment: Assuming the comment "don't use v" isn't lying, any remotely-half-baked optimizer will examine `v` usage in the first example, see the expression `v-5` never changes because `v` never changes, nor is put in a position where it *may* change, and perform the computation *once*. If it didn't your optimizer sucks. Compile to asm and check the instructions if you're really worried about it.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'll see if I can figure out how to compile to asm. (And understand the result.) I'm mostly curious, more than worried. I was asked to write highly-efficient code and I'm not sure which is the most efficient. Setting the value outside of the loop or doing it like this. In any case, I want to be able to back up my decision. For now, I'm using GCC, but in the end, it will be run on VC++. I don't know if VC++ is half-baked.

Comment: @eje211I hate that kind of mandate.  Code should be written to be clear and maintainable.  After that if you profile it and find the performance is not acceptable then you look at where the bottle necks our and see if you can fix them.  I am not a big fan of pre-optimizations.

Comment: What is this "C/C++" of which you speak?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's a low-level operation that could work in either. In C++, I actually define setV as `void setV(int & v)`, which is not possible in pure C, but the loop syntax is common to both.

Comment: @eje211: The answer may be completely different between the two (and passing a reference rather than a pointer in particular could make a huge difference to optimisation opportunities!). Please ask about one language at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit:

This was an interesting question for an unexpected reason. It's more a question of the compiler avoiding the obtuse case of an unintended aliasing of `v`. If the compiler can prove that this won't happen (version 2) then we get better code.

The lesson here is to be more concerned with eliminating aliasing than trying to do the optimiser's job for it.

Making the copy cv actually presented the biggest optimisation (elision of redundant memory fetches), even though at a first glance it would appear to be (slightly) less efficient.

### original answer and demo:

Let's see:

given:

```
extern void setV(int*);
extern void do_something(int i);

void test1()
{
    int v;
    setV(&v);
    for (int i = 0; i < v - 5; i++) {
    // Do stuff here, but don't use v.
      do_something(i);
    }
}


void test2()
{
    int v;
    setV(&v);
    const int cv = v;
    for (int i = 0; i < cv - 5; i++) {
      // Do stuff here. Changing cv is actually impossible.
      do_something(i);
    }  
}
```

compile on gcc5.3 with `-x c++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall`

gives:

```
test1():
        pushq   %rbx
        subq    $16, %rsp
        leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
        call    setV(int*)
        cmpl    $5, 12(%rsp)
        jle     .L1
        xorl    %ebx, %ebx
.L5:
        movl    %ebx, %edi
        addl    $1, %ebx
        call    do_something(int)
        movl    12(%rsp), %eax
        subl    $5, %eax
        cmpl    %ebx, %eax
        jg      .L5
.L1:
        addq    $16, %rsp
        popq    %rbx
        ret
test2():
        pushq   %rbp
        pushq   %rbx
        subq    $24, %rsp
        leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
        call    setV(int*)
        movl    12(%rsp), %eax
        cmpl    $5, %eax
        jle     .L8
        leal    -5(%rax), %ebp
        xorl    %ebx, %ebx
.L12:
        movl    %ebx, %edi
        addl    $1, %ebx
        call    do_something(int)
        cmpl    %ebp, %ebx
        jne     .L12
.L8:
        addq    $24, %rsp
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

The second form is better on this compiler.

Comment: Keep in mind if the compiler isn't using whole program optimization, it *can't* optimize away the evaluation in the first case because it doesn't know that `v` isn't aliased away in `setV` and mutated in `do_something`.

Comment: @MarkB v is local to the function. There is no legitimate access to v from do_something (which takes its argument by value) so the compiler is free to assume no aliasing, as it does in test2().

Comment: `setV` gets the address of the local `v` and sticks it in `global_v_ptr`. Then `do_something` accesses `v` through `*global_v_ptr` and updates the local variable legally.

Comment: @MarkB ah right, so in test2 were proving to the compiler that there is no causal relationship between the call and the end of loop condition. That in itself is probably a winning argument for using the extra variable in the second form.

Comment: If you are going to go to the trouble of adding `const int cv = v;` and iterating while `i < cv-5`, why not set cv=v-5 and interate while `i < cv` ? As a code maintainer, if I see math inside the for-construct it would imply to me that there is a possibility that one (or more) of the variable(s) in that expression MIGHT change somewhere in the loop, either directly of as a side effect of a function call.

Comment: @FredK Well, the question is less about what's the best solution and more about how it works. In my real code, I did `v -= 5`, because `v` was never used after the  `while` loop. But I don't want to adopt the attitude of "it works; I don't care how." If I just do `v -= 5`, then I don't understand the language any better.

Comment: @eje211 this was an interesting question for an unexpected reason. It's more a question of the compiler avoiding the obtuse case of an unintended aliasing of v. If the compiler can prove that this won't happen (version 2) then we get better code. The lesson here is to be more concerned with eliminating aliasing than doing the compilers job for it. Making the copy cv actually presented the biggest optimisation (elision of redundant memory fetches). Interesting eh?